# How to make the application window maximized by default

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

How I can make my Xamarin.Forms UWP application have its main window maximized upon its launch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maximize UWP app window on launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273754/maximize-uwp-app-window-on-launch)

Comment: @Dishant I tried that solution, but for some reason classes that are used in the method provided do not exist in the current context.

Comment: Did you try adding missing namespaces? Also, can you share on what did you tried so far?

Comment: @Dishant I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, it did work. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, it appears OP might have done what I initially did -- tried to insert that answer into the Forms version of `App.xaml.cs`. You have to edit `App.xaml.cs` _**in the UWP project**_ for it to work without complaining about references [after you add one].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this answer: [Maximize UWP app window on launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273754/maximize-uwp-app-window-on-launch) as @Dishant says but you should add this code to method `OnLaunched` into `App` class into `App.xaml.cs` file of your project UWP and add correct namespaces like this:

```cs
using Windows.Graphics.Display;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;

sealed partial class App : Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
    /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
/* ************** CALL METHOD HERE ************** */
        MaximizeWindowOnLoad();
        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }

/* ************** SEE HERE ************** */
    private void MaximizeWindowOnLoad()
    {
        var view = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

        // Get the screen resolution (APIs available from 14393 onward).
        var resolution = new Size(view.ScreenWidthInRawPixels, view.ScreenHeightInRawPixels);

        // Calculate the screen size in effective pixels.
        // Note the height of the Windows Taskbar is ignored here since the app will only be given the maxium available size.
        var scale = view.ResolutionScale == ResolutionScale.Invalid ? 1 : view.RawPixelsPerViewPixel;
        var bounds = new Size(resolution.Width / scale, resolution.Height / scale);

        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchViewSize = new Size(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.PreferredLaunchViewSize;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
    private void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
    /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
    /// of memory still intact.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```