# How i can maximize UWP after launch?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I'm launch my app when the user logs in to Windows. I have the appropriate Extension ([StartupTask class](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask?view=winrt-19041#uwp-app-startup-task-extension)) set in Package.appxmanifest, and I can get the app to launch when I log in to Windows, as expected. However, the app minimize after start. How i can his maximize after start?

I tried the ways from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273754/maximize-uwp-app-window-on-launch)

Comment: Please share with us some code that shows how did you try to tackle this issue.

Comment: @PeterCsala I upd question

Answer (score 0):

the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.startuptask) explains this:

> UWP apps must call RequestEnableAsync from a UI thread to trigger a user-consent dialog. If the user consents, the UWP app will then start on startup or user log in. Note that UWP startup apps will start minimized.

Minimizing when starting the application is the default behavior. This is to ensure a good user experience for Store app by default. Currently, UWP does not provide related APIs to modify this behavior.

Comment: I've seen the documentation and read this. Previously, this suited the customer, but now he wanted to change this behavior. Are there any "crutches" to change this or do still need to use some other autorun mechanism. 
Main demand was switch on/off autorun from application settings.

Comment: Hello, the core of this problem is that UWP does not have the authority to "wake up" itself to the foreground. This is a permission design. If you need this feature, you can report in the Feedback Hub app.